# IntelliJ support for Cucumber 4.7

Tags: java, intellij-idea, cucumber

The project I am working on was recently upgraded to use cucumber version 4.72. This completely broke IntelliJ integration. I believe the reason is that in this version of Cucumber, package structure has changed.

As an example, in the "old" version, step definition classes would extend from `cucumber.api.java8.En`, whereas in the "new" version it's `io.cucumber.java8.En`.  As a result, IntelliJ cannot find step definitions.  There is a multitude of other changes.

I'm on the latest version of IntelliJ Ultimate (2019.2.2, dated September 6, 2019) and the Cucumber plugin is listed as "bundled".

Is there any trick to getting IntelliJ to work with the latest version of Cucumber or do I have to patiently wait until some future IntelliJ version will add this support?  If the second, does anyone know when this may be forthcoming?

Comment: There is related issue on YouTrack: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219739. Fix should be provided in nearest updates.

Answer (score 0):

About this issue, Andrey Vokin who is the fixer of this issue was shared a plugin in the comments, I am using it for now and it works fine. Otherwise we need to wait for next fix/release. This plug-in was for cucumber v 4.5.1 however my colleague is fine with that plugin on  cucumber 4.7.x

[Plug-in download link](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/_persistent/cucumber-java.zip?file=74-693360&c=false&updated=1563554407688)

[Youtrack Issue : IDEA-217391](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-217391)

Comment: I attempted to install this plugin, however got an error: _Plugin 'Cucumber for Java' is incompatible with this installation_

Comment: Hi @AleksG, please try to choose other files inside the zip

Comment: No luck. Inside the zip file there are only a few jar files. Trying to select the jar file results in the same error message.

Comment: Also, reading through the youtrack issue, I believe this plugin is for community addition. I have Ultimate - possibly this is why the plugin wouldn't install.

Comment: Also quite interesting... There was a new intellij release today - 2019.2.3 - but the updated plugin is not included in it.

Comment: @AleksG first I am using ultimate edition but this plugin works.